# Signal SIGABRT when trying to save fields to CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to save a number of fields into `CoreData`, I have an entity called `ArtworkSaved` with generated subclasses(`ArtworkSaved+CoreDataClass.swift` and `ArtworkSaved+CoreDataProperties`).

I have also moved the `persistentContainer` out of AppDelegate creating a new own class for it `PersistenceServ.swift`

```
    class PersistenceServ
    {
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

private init() {}

static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}

static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
     */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NAME OF PROJECT")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

static func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("SAVED")
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is called in this section of code:

```
         func save(artworkPass:artwork)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let saveArt = ArtworkSaved(context: PersistenceServ.context)

        saveArt.artist = artworkPass.artist
        saveArt.building = artworkPass.location
        saveArt.enabled = artworkPass.enabled
        saveArt.fileName = artworkPass.fileName
        saveArt.id = artworkPass.id
        saveArt.information = artworkPass.Information
        saveArt.lastModified = artworkPass.lastModifed

        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)

        saveArt.lastUpdate = result
        saveArt.lat = artworkPass.lat
        saveArt.locationNotes = artworkPass.locationNotes
        saveArt.long = artworkPass.long
        saveArt.title = artworkPass.title
        saveArt.yearOfWork = artworkPass.yearOfWork

        PersistenceServ.saveContext()
    }
```

and the error falls within the `AppDelegate` class.

[image: Sigabrt error]

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information. And rather than static methods use a singleton (instance).

Comment: @vadian Set a breakpoint where exactly?

Comment: The Exception Breakpoint is a global breakpoint.

Comment: It stops on the line `let saveArt...` @vadian

Comment: Hi, I've made a test project with given code almost the same, excluding setting all properties to `ArtworkSaved` entity, but CoreData stack, save methods etc are exactly the same. And it works fine. It seems that there is not enough information to reproduce your crash. Could you provide more details?